# How to read a really long string from STDIN in ruby?

Tags: ruby, string, stdin

I've been using `STDIN.gets` read strings from stdin in ruby, but I just noticed that these strings must be shorter than 1024 characters. None of the following methods will read strings longer than 1024 characters:

```
STDIN.gets
STDIN.gets(2000)
STDIN.read
STDIN.readline
```

In fact, the interpreter won't even allow the full 1024 characters to be sent, since it needs to add the line break, so a user can only type at most 1023 characters and press `return`.

You could break the string into multiple lines and then remove the line breaks afterwards, but these strings are likely being copy/pasted, so it would not be feasible to do it, unless there's a way to make the interpreter do it automatically.

How can I read a string that's longer than this 1024 limit?

Comment: This is a limit of the TTY. More [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/204815/218427). It's fairly universal across TTYs, with varying limits depending on OS.

Answer (score 0):

The Readline gem does not seem to have this limitation. In my testing, lines of well over 1400 characters caused no problem. This was also true of my version, mini_readline. I suspect that this is due to the fact that both of these gems operate the TTY in raw mode and do buffering, editing etc, in Ruby, not using the system buffering.

https://rubygems.org/gems/rb-readline